# ClientAPI.AddButtonConfirm

Tags: dotnetnuke, message, confirmation, box

I would like to ask how to use Confirmation Message box (ClientAPI.AddButtonConfirm(WebControl wc,string str)) in dotnetnuke.

My case is I have items in Repeater control and I have a function to select multiple items and delete when "Delete Selected" button was clicked.
My function is worked. But I would like to show confirmation message before the delete function is trigger that allow user to cancel the process.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I got it now. Actually it was easy thing

in **.ascx** file my code is

asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server" OnClick="btnDelete_Click"  CssClass="dnnSecondaryAction" Text="Delete" Visible="false"/>

and in **.cs** file

ClientAPI.AddButtonConfirm(btnDelete, "Are you sure to delete this entry");

Then when click the button this will display Dotnetnuke confirmation message box.

Answer (score 0):

Add `OnClientClick` property in your button. You can update confirmation message as you need.

```
OnClientClick="javascript:return window.confirm('Do you want to remove this Brand?')"
```

Comment: Hi, Dexterity I got it now. Thank you for your answer

here is my .ascx file
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server" OnClick="btnDelete_Click"  CssClass="dnnSecondaryAction" Text="Delete" Visible="false" />

in .cs file I put this
ClientAPI.AddButtonConfirm(btnDelete, "Are you sure to delete this entry");

so this will display with dnn pop-up confirmation message.

I know your answer is true but I don't want to use normal javascript pop-up.